# Recycler view item is gets truncated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am facing a strange behaviour with recycler view items. The textviews are supposed to be match parents but when I run it I get the following

[image]

As you can see all the items are truncated although its parent (the outer blue box) is match parent as can be seen.

If I scroll down or up then the items occupies the space as expected. See first item below which I scrolled it up and down:

[image]

The funny thing that after the last image above, if I pop up the keyboard back up (or hide) it then all items are truncated back to the first image.

Something between recycler view, keyboard and the dialog this whole thing this in is causing issues

Parent:

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSearch"     
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        
.
.
.
.

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvLocSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
```

Item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/main_light_grey"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLine1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="line 1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLine2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="line 2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDistance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="# km"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ivIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivIcon" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: For the keyboard issue, may be `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|keyboard"`  at manifest, activity section can make sense

Comment: Thank you. I tried it. No luck

Comment: tvDistance width is wrap_content, plus what is ivIcon? Can you send us a related image like I see text as "line 2" but nowhere in the picture can I see "line 2" written. It will be easy to compare and locate where the problem is

Comment: tvDistance is not the issue. tvLine1 and tvLine2 are the ones being trucated

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep tvDistance's width as match parent as other widgets.

Replace this line

```
  android:id="@+id/tvDistance"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

with this one

```
 android:id="@+id/tvDistance"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: tvLine1 is match parent. Setting distance to match parent or wrap content should have an effect

Comment: Yes, It will have. Try to change and check the results.